# Different result on using onnxruntime c++ and python

Tags: python, c++, deep-learning, inference, onnxruntime

Have a nice day

I have a detector model written in Python, and I`m trying to convert it into C++ and then compile it.

This detector model has been exported in Onnx format, and everything is fine when I`m trying to infer or run in Python. In the following, I put this model class that I use it.

```py
class Detector:
    def __init__(self, model_file: str, nms_thresh: float = .4, det_thresh: float = .5, min_res: float = 20,
                 input_size: Tuple[int, int] = (480, 640)) -> None:
        self.session = ort.InferenceSession(model_file, None,providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'])
        self.center_cache = {}
        self.nms_thresh = nms_thresh
        self.det_thresh = det_thresh
        self.min_res = min_res

        self.input_name = self.session.get_inputs()[0].name
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_names = [o.name for o in self.session.get_outputs()]
        self.fmc = 3
        self.input_mean = 127.5
        self.input_std = 128.0
        self._feat_stride_fpn = [8, 16, 32]
        self._num_anchors = 2

    def forward(self, img: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        scores_list = []
        bboxes_list = []
        kps_list = []

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1.0 / self.input_std, tuple(img.shape[0:2][::-1]),
                                     (self.input_mean, self.input_mean, self.input_mean), swapRB=True)
        net_outs = self.session.run(self.output_names, {self.input_name: blob})
        input_height = blob.shape[2]
        input_width = blob.shape[3]
        fmc = self.fmc

        for idx, stride in enumerate(self._feat_stride_fpn):
            scores = net_outs[idx]
            bbox_predicts = net_outs[idx + fmc]
            bbox_predicts = bbox_predicts * stride
            kps_predicts = net_outs[idx + fmc * 2] * stride
            height = input_height // stride
            width = input_width // stride
            key = (height, width, stride)
            if key in self.center_cache:
                anchor_centers = self.center_cache[key]
            else:
                anchor_centers = np.stack(np.mgrid[:height, :width][::-1], axis=-1).astype(np.float32)
                anchor_centers = (anchor_centers * stride).reshape((-1, 2))
                if self._num_anchors > 1:
                    anchor_centers = np.stack([anchor_centers] * self._num_anchors, axis=1).reshape((-1, 2))
                if len(self.center_cache) < 100:
                    self.center_cache[key] = anchor_centers
            # with size of anchors
            scores = scores[:len(anchor_centers)]
            bbox_predicts = bbox_predicts[:len(anchor_centers)]
            kps_predicts = kps_predicts[:len(anchor_centers)]
            pos_indices = np.where(scores >= self.det_thresh)[0]
            bboxes = distance2bbox(anchor_centers, bbox_predicts)
            pos_scores = scores[pos_indices]
            pos_bboxes = bboxes[pos_indices]
            scores_list.append(pos_scores)
            bboxes_list.append(pos_bboxes)
            key_points = distance2kps(anchor_centers, kps_predicts)
            key_points = key_points.reshape((key_points.shape[0], -1, 2))
            pos_key_points = key_points[pos_indices]
            kps_list.append(pos_key_points)

        scores = np.vstack(scores_list)
        bboxes_list = np.vstack(bboxes_list)
        kps_list = np.vstack(kps_list)

        # cv2.imshow('blob', np.transpose(blob[0], [1, 2, 0]))

        return scores, bboxes_list, kps_list

    def detect(self, img: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:

        ref_size = img.shape[:2]
        img = cv2.resize(img, self.input_size[::-1])
        res_size = img.shape[:2]
        det_scale = (ref_size[0] / res_size[0], ref_size[1] / res_size[1])
        scores, boxes, points = self.forward(img)
        order = scores.ravel().argsort()[::-1]

        # Order
        scores = scores[order, :]
        boxes = boxes[order, :]
        points = points[order, :]

        # Scale
        boxes[:, [0, 2]] *= det_scale[1]
        boxes[:, [1, 3]] *= det_scale[0]
        points[:, :, [0]] *= det_scale[1]
        points[:, :, [1]] *= det_scale[0]

        keep_indices = self.nms(boxes, scores)

        # Keep
        scores = scores[keep_indices, :]
        boxes = boxes[keep_indices, :]
        points = points[keep_indices, :]

        # Keep min resolution
        if len(boxes) > 0:
            wh = boxes[:, [2, 3]] - boxes[:, [0, 1]]
            wh = wh[:, 0] * wh[:, 1]
            min_res_idx = np.where(wh > self.min_res)[0]
            scores = scores[min_res_idx, :]
            boxes = boxes[min_res_idx, :]
            points = points[min_res_idx, :]

        return scores, boxes, points
        # cv2.imshow('blob', np.transpose(blob[0], (1, 2, 0)))

    def nms(self, boxes: np.ndarray, scores: np.ndarray):
        thresh = self.nms_thresh
        x1 = boxes[:, 0]
        y1 = boxes[:, 1]
        x2 = boxes[:, 2]
        y2 = boxes[:, 3]

        areas = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
        order = scores.ravel().argsort()[::-1]
        keep = []
        while order.size > 0:
            i = order[0]
            keep.append(i)
            xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[order[1:]])
            yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[order[1:]])
            xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[order[1:]])
            yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[order[1:]])

            w = np.maximum(0.0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
            h = np.maximum(0.0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)
            inter = w * h
            ovr = inter / (areas[i] + areas[order[1:]] - inter)

            inds = np.where(ovr <= thresh)[0]
            order = order[inds + 1]

        return keep
```

Unfortunately, I have converted this class into C++ version, and everything looks fine but I cannot get the same result on our dataset.

Assume I put a video into these two versions, all objects in the C++ version have a very close to zero probability and I cannot use the same confidence threshold for these two versions

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <onnxruntime/onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

struct AnchorBox{
    float cx;
    float cy;
    float s_kx;
    float s_ky;
};

struct Bbox{
    float x1;
    float y1;
    float x2;
    float y2;
};

struct ObjectMeta
{
    Bbox bbox;
    float score;
};

template <typename T> T vectorProduct(const std::vector<T>& v){
    return accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),1,std::multiplies<T>());
}

void nms(std::vector<ObjectMeta>& input_boxes,std::vector<ObjectMeta>& output_boxes, float nms_threshold){
    
    std::sort(input_boxes.begin(), input_boxes.end(),
            [](const ObjectMeta &a, const ObjectMeta &b)
            { return a.score > b.score; });

    const unsigned int box_num = input_boxes.size();
    std::vector<int> merged(box_num, 0);

    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < box_num; ++i)
    {
        if (merged[i]) continue;
        std::vector<ObjectMeta> buf;

        buf.push_back(input_boxes[i]);
        merged[i] = 1;

        for (unsigned int j = i + 1; j < box_num; ++j)
        {
            if (merged[j]) continue;

            float area1 = (input_boxes[i].bbox.x2 - input_boxes[i].bbox.x1+1) * (input_boxes[i].bbox.y2 - input_boxes[i].bbox.y1 + 1);
            float area2 = (input_boxes[j].bbox.x2 - input_boxes[j].bbox.x1+1) * (input_boxes[j].bbox.y2 - input_boxes[j].bbox.y1 + 1);

            float xx1 = input_boxes[i].bbox.x1 >input_boxes[j].bbox.x1?input_boxes[i].bbox.x1:input_boxes[j].bbox.x1;
            float yy1 = input_boxes[i].bbox.y1 >input_boxes[j].bbox.y1?input_boxes[i].bbox.y1:input_boxes[j].bbox.y1;
            float xx2 = input_boxes[i].bbox.x2 >input_boxes[j].bbox.x2?input_boxes[i].bbox.x2:input_boxes[j].bbox.x2;
            float yy2 = input_boxes[i].bbox.y2 >input_boxes[j].bbox.y2?input_boxes[i].bbox.y2:input_boxes[j].bbox.y2;

            float wb = xx2-xx1+1;
            float hb =yy2-yy1+1;

            float inner = (wb>0?wb:0)*(hb>0?hb:0);

            float iou = inner / (area1+area2-inner);

            if (iou > nms_threshold)
            {
                merged[j] = 1;
                buf.push_back(input_boxes[j]);
            }

        }
        output_boxes.push_back(buf[0]);
    }
}

Bbox distance2bbox(const AnchorBox &anchor,const Bbox& distance){
    return {
        anchor.cx - distance.x1,
        anchor.cy - distance.y1,
        anchor.cx + distance.x2,
        anchor.cy + distance.y2
    };
}

template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v){
    os<<"[";
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        os<<v[i];
        if(i>100){
            break;
        }
        if(i!=v.size()-1){
            os<<", ";
        }
    }
    os<<"]";
    return os;
}


template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>*v){
    os<<"[";
    for(int i=0;i<v->size();i++){
        if(i<20){
            os<<v+i;
            if(i!=v->size()-1){
                os<<", ";
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    os<<"]";
    return os;
}

// Types
typedef std::vector<int64_t> vInt64Shape;

// Define some constant variables
const static std::string appname{"FatechV"};
const static bool useCuda{true};
static int deviceId{-1};
const static unsigned short int MAJOR_VER{0};
const static unsigned short int MINOR_VER{0};
const static unsigned short int PATCH_VER{1};

// Detector specification
const static std::string DetModelPath{"/home/ixion/Projects/fatechCTL/services/face/data/models/Face/det_10g.onnx"};
const static int fmc{3};
const static std::vector<int> feat_stride_fpn{8,16,32};
const static int anchors = 2;
const static std::vector<int> inputDims{640,480};
const static float input_mean{127.5};
const static float input_std{128.0};
const static float conf_thresh = 0.5;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout<<appname<<" "<<MAJOR_VER<<"."<<MINOR_VER<<"."<<PATCH_VER<<std::endl;

    Ort::SessionOptions session_options;
    Ort::Env env{ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_ERROR};
    if(useCuda){
        cudaGetDevice(&deviceId);
        cudaDeviceProp cudaProp;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&cudaProp,deviceId);
        std::cout<<cudaProp.name<<std::endl;

        OrtCUDAProviderOptions cuda_option;
        cuda_option.device_id = deviceId;
        cuda_option.cudnn_conv_algo_search = OrtCudnnConvAlgoSearchExhaustive;
        cuda_option.gpu_mem_limit = static_cast<int>(SIZE_MAX*1024*1024);
        cuda_option.arena_extend_strategy = 1;
        cuda_option.has_user_compute_stream = 1;
        cuda_option.default_memory_arena_cfg = nullptr;

        session_options.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cuda_option);
        session_options.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_ALL);
    }


    // Start Detector Session
    std::unique_ptr<Ort::Session> session;
    std::vector<const char*> inputNames{"input.1"};
    vInt64Shape inputShape{1,3,inputDims[0],inputDims[1]};
    std::vector<const char*> outputNames{"448", "471", "494", "451", "474", "497", "454", "477", "500"};
    vInt64Shape outputShape;

    session = std::make_unique<Ort::Session>(env,DetModelPath.c_str(),session_options);

    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;

    outputShape = session->GetOutputTypeInfo(0).GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();

    std::cout<<session->GetOutputCount()<<std::endl;

    for(int i=0;i<session->GetOutputCount();i++){
        outputShape = session->GetOutputTypeInfo(i).GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();

        std::cout<<i+1<<" "<<outputShape<<" "<<vectorProduct(outputShape)<<std::endl;
    }

    std::map<int,std::vector<AnchorBox>> cached_anchors;
    // Create anchors
    for(int k=0;k<feat_stride_fpn.size();k++){
        int stride = feat_stride_fpn[k];
        int heightR = std::ceil(inputDims[1]/stride);
        int widthR = std::ceil(inputDims[0]/stride);


        std::vector<AnchorBox> anchors_boxes;
        for(int na=0;na<anchors;na++){
            for(int h=0;h<heightR;h++){
                for(int w=0;w<widthR;w++){
                float cx = ((float)w+0.5f) * (float)stride;
                float cy = ((float)h+0.5f) * (float)stride;
                    anchors_boxes.push_back(AnchorBox{cx,cy});
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout<<anchors_boxes.size()<<std::endl;
        cached_anchors[stride] = anchors_boxes;
    }

    // End Detector Session

    
    const std::string file_name = "/home/ixion/Projects/fatechCTL/services/face/data/videos/Cathy_ONeil.mp4";
    cv::namedWindow("Main",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::VideoCapture vision(file_name);
    while (vision.isOpened()){
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::Mat fframe;
        bool ret = vision.read(frame);
        if(frame.empty()){
            break;
        }
        frame.copyTo(fframe);
        cv::Size input_size{inputDims[1],inputDims[0]};
        cv::resize(fframe, fframe, input_size);
        

        size_t inputTensorSize = vectorProduct(inputShape);
        std::vector<float> inputTensorValue(inputTensorSize);
        
        // Frame specs
        double scalefactor = 1/input_std;
        cv::Scalar means {input_mean,input_mean,input_mean};
        

        cv::Mat matf;
        frame.convertTo(matf, CV_32FC3);
        cv::cvtColor(matf,matf,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        matf = (matf - input_mean) * scalefactor;

        cv::Mat resize_mat_ref;
        cv::resize(matf, resize_mat_ref, input_size);
        std::cout<<resize_mat_ref.rows<<" "<<resize_mat_ref.cols<<std::endl;
        std::vector<cv::Mat> mat_channels;
        cv::split(resize_mat_ref, mat_channels);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            std::memcpy(inputTensorValue.data() + i * (inputShape[3] * inputShape[2]),
                        mat_channels.at(i).data,inputShape[2] * inputShape[3] * sizeof(float));
        }
            
        std::vector<Ort::Value> inputTensors;
        Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);
        inputTensors.push_back(std::move(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(memoryInfo,inputTensorValue.data(),inputTensorSize,inputShape.data(),inputShape.size())));

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::vector<Ort::Value> outputTensors = session->Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr},inputNames.data(),inputTensors.data(),size_t(1),outputNames.data(),size_t(9));
        assert(outputTensors.size()==9 && outputTensors.front().IsTensor());
        std::vector<float> confVector;
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> bboxVector;
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> kpsVector;

        std::vector<ObjectMeta> metas;

        for(int i=0;i<feat_stride_fpn.size();i++){

            auto confSize = vectorProduct(outputTensors[i].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape());
            auto bboxSize = vectorProduct(outputTensors[i+fmc].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape());
            auto kpsSize = vectorProduct(outputTensors[i+fmc*2].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape());

            auto confShape = outputTensors[i].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();
            auto bboxShape = outputTensors[i+fmc].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();
            auto kpsShape = outputTensors[i+fmc*2].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();

            int stride = feat_stride_fpn[i];
            auto anchorStride = cached_anchors[stride];
            for(int j=0;j<confSize;j++){
                float score = outputTensors.at(i).At<float>({j,0});
                if(score<conf_thresh){
                    continue;
                }
                ObjectMeta obj;
                obj.score = score;

                Bbox bbox {
                    outputTensors.at(i+fmc).At<float>({j,0})*stride,
                    outputTensors.at(i+fmc).At<float>({j,1})*stride,
                    outputTensors.at(i+fmc).At<float>({j,2})*stride,
                    outputTensors.at(i+fmc).At<float>({j,3})*stride,
                };

                obj.bbox = distance2bbox(anchorStride[j],bbox);
                

                metas.push_back(obj);

            }


        }

        std::vector<ObjectMeta> outputMetas;

        nms(metas,outputMetas,.4);
        std::cout<<outputMetas.size()<<std::endl;

        for(auto obj:outputMetas){
            std::cout<<"["<<obj.score<<", "<<obj.bbox.x1<<", "<<obj.bbox.y1<<", "<<obj.bbox.x2<<", "<<obj.bbox.y2<<"]\n";
            cv::rectangle(fframe,cv::Point(obj.bbox.x1,obj.bbox.y1),cv::Point(obj.bbox.x2,obj.bbox.y2),cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        cv::imshow("Main",resize_mat_ref);

        if(cv::waitKey(10)==27){
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The differences can be found **net_outs** (python) and **outputTensors** (C++).
Also, I checked the processing steps and there is no problem and it looks fine.

Please let me know if there is any mistake:))

Comment: Your question needs more focus. Try, step by step, and verify which parts of the code produces the correct outputs, until you find something that is different between the two. Also remove commented code if it isn't relevant - or why is it there?

Comment: The default type of `float` in Python is `float64` and the nearest equivalent in C++ is `double`, not `float`.    Also, Python uses IEEE floating point representations, but, although C++ implementations *often* use IEEE floating point, the C++ gives *no guarantee* of that - and there are real-world implementations that do not.   Key lesson:  even if some code constructs look the same (and even if they use the same keywords) there are *typically* actual differences between programming languages.

Comment: Alright, that`s a good point. let me check the types and I`ll know you. @Peter

Comment: @Jeppe I cleaned the commented codes and mentioned which lines (results) are different.